# getting value from jQuery modal window page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a modal window on a page, inside the window it loads a .aspx page within it using an iframe.

I would like the ability on click of a link within the modal window (.aspx) to send back a value to the page that holds the modal window.

Do you know how I can do that? It's basically so I can use the modal as a search, select an item then do things with it in the previous window.

Thanks.

Comment: try using `parent.$('#receiver').val($('#sender').val());` on your function inside the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate from the iframe with the caller window you use the `window.top.document` or the `window.parent.document` which is suits you.

With simple javascript you look for elements like that:

```
window.top.document.getElementById("ControlIdToFindOnTop")
```

and because you work on asp.net make sure that you have set `static` control id, on your control because the two pages can not communicate to locate the control id using the usual `ControlIdToFindOnTop.ControlID`

Now using jQuery you can do the same, locate an object on top windows as:

```
jQuery("#ControlIdToFindOnTop", window.top.document)
```

And to call functions from iframe that exist on top window you can call something like:

```
window.top.FunctionToRun();
```

After you have the control object, you can read the value, the text, their properties, etc...

Comment: I got it to work with window.top.document.getelementbyid. Do you know if you can also close the modal window from the iframe using something similar?

Comment: @connersz Yes you do, the same way, I have write how to call a function, and you can close it that way